# Unable to load certificate, Xcode builds fails to install certificate (VSTS/Azure DevOps, YAML Pipeline)

Tags: ios, xcode, azure-devops

I'm using the YAML pipelines in Azure DevOps, to build an iOS app.

My YAML looks as follows:

```
# Xcode
# Build, test, and archive an Xcode workspace on macOS.
# Add steps that install certificates, test, sign, and distribute the app, save build artifacts, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/vsts/pipelines/languages/xcode

pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS 10.13'

steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'FILE_ID'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'

- task: InstallAppleProvisioningProfile@1
  displayName: 'Install an Apple provisioning profile'
  inputs:
    provProfileSecureFile: 'FILE_ID'

- task: CocoaPods@0
  displayName: 'pod install using the CocoaPods task with defaults'

- task: Xcode@5
  displayName: 'Xcode build'
  inputs:
    xcWorkspacePath: 'MyApp.xcworkspace'
    scheme: 'MyApp'
    xcodeVersion: 'Default'
    signingOption: manual
    signingIdentity: '$(APPLE_CERTIFICATE_SIGNING_IDENTITY)'
    provisioningProfileUuid: '$(APPLE_PROV_PROFILE_UUID)'
```

I'm getting an error in the Install Apple Certificate step:

```
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4496940Z ##[section]Starting: Install an Apple certificate
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4786520Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4786680Z Task         : Install Apple Certificate
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4786800Z Description  : Install an Apple certificate required to build on a macOS agent
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4786940Z Version      : 2.137.0
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4787050Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4787160Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=862067)
2018-10-02T20:08:23.4787280Z ==============================================================================
2018-10-02T20:08:24.9657760Z [command]/usr/local/bin/openssl pkcs12 -in /Users/vsts/agent/2.140.2/work/_temp/PWEKQ6YCZA.p12 -nokeys -passin pass:*** | /usr/local/bin/openssl x509 -noout -fingerprint
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0196330Z 140735606010824:error:0D0680A8:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_CHECK_TLEN:wrong tag:tasn_dec.c:1220:
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0197000Z 140735606010824:error:0D07803A:asn1 encoding routines:ASN1_ITEM_EX_D2I:nested asn1 error:tasn_dec.c:386:Type=PKCS12
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0332040Z unable to load certificate
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0332600Z 140735606010824:error:0906D06C:PEM routines:PEM_read_bio:no start line:pem_lib.c:697:Expecting: TRUSTED CERTIFICATE
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0437120Z ##[error]Error: /usr/local/bin/openssl failed with return code: 1
2018-10-02T20:08:25.0514080Z ##[section]Finishing: Install an Apple certificate
```

Any idea what could be wrong here?

I also tried setting up a build pipeline in Azure DevOps from the UI, but I get the same result.

Comment: I'm getting exactly the same problem. Have you managed to get anywhere with this?

Comment: No I'm still stuck.

Comment: The error usually occurs when the certificate format is invalid, can you check that? Can you install the file with the same command on your local machine?

Comment: Really happy to see this question here, I'm hitting a very similar problem. I opened a request for clarification in the documentation on Github (https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/vsts-docs/issues/1930) but it has gone unacknowledged so far.

Are you successfully able to reference your certificate? I'm getting specifically this error: "Job MacOSX: Step input certSecureFile references secure file my_file_name.p12 which could not be found. The secure file does not exist or has not been authorized for use." I've tried a few things in my YAML and can't get past this error

Comment: @EddieChen-MSFT I tried, and I got the same error on my Mac. So the format of the certificate was indeed the problem.

I used fastlane match to store certs, apparently they do something different with them...

I resolved this by exporting the certificate from my keychain instead, uploaded as secure file etc. and now it works.

Comment: @ncthom91 I got your error as well, I ended up creating the build definition in UI, and then getting the YAML from that. Reference to secure file IDs was then correct.

Comment: @MartinHN interesting, I tried the same thing and received the same error. So you're using the long UUID string? Did you add a file extension or anything? I'll take another stab at it...

Comment: Ok I was able to get my InstallAppleCertificate step working as you did only after destroying and recreating my pipeline (same repository, same pipelines.yml). I suppose it had something to do with refreshing secure files authorization.. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2):

You seem to have been following [this guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/apps/mobile/app-signing?view=azure-devops&tabs=apple-install-during-build) just like I did.

The problem seems to be in reading the `$(P12password)` variable. I tried entering the certificate password in the **Install Apple Certificate** task directly without a variable and it went through.

Hope we can improve this answer together to make it a "solution", not just a workaround.

Answer (score 2):

For what it's worth, I came here with this exact error but resolved it by ensuring the certificate password had no special characters. There seems to be a problem escaping the password (notably the £ symbol) when the build runs.

Answer (score 0):

In order to allow the task to read variables like your `$(P12password)` you need to link the variable group.
For a build pipeline, for instance, you can do this in the UI in "Edit" mode. Next to the "YAML" tab, you can find "Variables" with a sub-item "Variable groups" and a button "Link variable group", which allows you to select one from your Library.

The same goes for release pipelines where the "Variables" tab is next to the "Tasks"-dropdown.

Details: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/library/variable-groups?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml

Answer (score 0):

This error comes when the Azure doesnt know how to access the variables.

Please note that in the below code we are not refering to any variable group:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS 10.13'

steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'FILE_ID'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
```

So when Agent macOS runs the task it doesnt have the password with it, it has the same concept as environment variables.

To make this work we have to define the variable group where the information is stored as below:

```
pool:
  vmImage: 'macOS 10.13'
variables:
  - group: 'suitableVariableGroupName'
steps:
- task: InstallAppleCertificate@2
  displayName: 'Install an Apple certificate'
  inputs:
    certSecureFile: 'FILE_ID'
    certPwd: '$(P12password)'
```

Please note that the variable group 'suitableVariableGroupName' should have a variable called: P12password and then a value assigned to it.